# How to set bitmap in ImageView after saved in server

Tags: java, android

I want to set bitmap in imageview after saved on the server. I tried a lot, it's saved in a server but not set in imageview. If I didn't send to the server means it fix in imageview. How to do both

Here my code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && data != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            mSelectedImageUri = getImageUri(this.getApplicationContext(), bitmap);
           // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(mSelectedImageUri));
            profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            getContentResolver().delete(mSelectedImageUri, null, null);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("format", splitFormat[1]);
                    jsonObject.put("accId",acc_id);
                    jsonObject.put("encodeImage",encodeTobase64(bitmap));
                    input = new StringEntityHC4(jsonObject.toString());
                    input.setContentType("application/json");
                    input.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                    UpdateProfilePicToServer();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you show method **UpdateProfilePicToServer();** So that we can know where we confirmed file is uploaded to server successfully.

Answer (score 4):

first approach is :

if u dont want to wait for successful upload on the server and then load the image in the imageview
then you can simple do

profilePic.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri)

and in case you want to wait for successful upload, then u can get the imageurl as the response , and use that url with picasso library to load image into your imageView as

Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(profilePic)

Note :- 
If are selecting image from memory,make sure u have storage read permissions

Comment: check your manifest , do u have required permissions,and check if u r getting and reference values in mSelectedImageUri and bitmap, use debug tools to view the image that u get

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: set breakpoint at mSelectedImageUri and at bitmap= ........       . and run debug , and view what bitmap or image do u actually get there

Answer (score 0):

You can set bitmap to imageview.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I already did.. Check my code : profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: getContentResolver().delete(mSelectedImageUri, null, null); Any reason doing this.

Comment: Yeah... In this line: mSelectedImageUri = getImageUri(this.getApplicationContext(), bitmap);                getImageUri method insert image in gallery.. For deleting that image, I used that line